# Why isn't this answer considered as "Not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

[image]

A mod declined my flag of "Not an answer" on that answer. You can take this answer as "Did you add this import?". Shouldn't it be a comment? I believe small things like this should be comments before they become answers, because otherwise they're useless.

**Note:** this is no duplicate, I'm not asking when I should flag, I'm asking why it was declined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I hope you realize I'm asking why it was declined, not if I should flag it.

Comment: ...and you can't determine one from the other? The duplicate tells you when you *should* flag, so the fact that this answer doesn't fall under those criteria tells you that you *shouldn't*. If you don't like that dupe, pick one of the hundreds of others.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So you're right now holding tight to the fact that I haven't read that question?

Comment: You certainly don't appear to have read the answer, but I don't see any point in discussing this with you further.

Comment: Did you not know an answer can be phrased as a question?

Answer (score 9):

For all you know, the asker might really have forgotten to add that import and adding it did actually solve their problem. That would have made such an answer anything *but* useless (although if that were indeed the case then conceivably the question could have been closed as "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers", but that doesn't make it any less of an answer).

Even if the asker's self-answer demonstrates that to not be the case, that doesn't rule out the possibility of the answer being an answer, it just means the answerer guessed wrong.